# Is it possible to write an admission controller for a node?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to inject a custom validation logic when a new node is added to the cluster. Concretely, I want to check if the id of the node matches a specific regex.
In other words, in addition of kubernetes validating the the node's certificate is signed by the trusted CA (`kubelet-certificate-authority` flag) and has the SAN in the form of `system:nodes`, I want to check what goes after `system:nodes:check_this_as_well`.
Is this possible with an admission controller?

Comment: Please do not [cross post questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/1143285/is-it-possible-to-write-an-admission-controller-for-a-node).